# creating logs in Django after Update

Tags: python, django, logging

I try to Implement an logger in Django. I had it allready working in Django Version 1.5 and Python 2.7.

But when I try to implement it on my actual Version(Django 2.0.8 and Python 3.6.5)
 I get the Error on the following Code in the manage.py:

```
import logging.config
import os
import sys
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(PROJECT_PATH)
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "ProjectServer.settings"

logging.config.fileConfig('ProjectServer/logging.ini')
try:
    import settings
except ImportError:
     import sys
     sys.stderr.write("Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing. ")
     sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     import django
     django.setup()

     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

The Exception i get:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
File "C:\path\ProjectServer\manage.py", line 10, in<module>
logging.config.fileConfig('ProjectServer/logging.ini')
```

My logging.ini:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler, rotatingFileHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,rotatingFileHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=logging.StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_rotatingFileHandler]
class=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
args=(r'c:\log\debug.log','maxBytes=1000000','backupCount=3')
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

I don´t really get how it would come to the Error. When I checked the Pythonversion I didn´t notice any changes regarding the Logging.

Afterwards i´m importing the Logging and use it like this in my Models and Views

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info('error creating calendar file')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator `>` in python 2.7 can be used with two different types like string and integer. Example:

```
s = "xxx"
n = 123
s > n // will output True
```

In python3 this operation is not allowed.

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Comparison operator `>` is described in a detailed way in [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

It seems that somewhere in your code you are trying to compare string vs integer.

EDIT (after OP posted the code)

The problem with `operator >` unsupported arguments occurs, because your `RotatingFileHandler` setting `maxBytes` is interpreted as a string instead of integer. You can fix this problem by providing the list of `RotatingFileHandler` constructor arguments without using keyword notation. Like this:

```
[handler_rotatingFileHandler]
class=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
args=(r'c:\log\debug.log', 'a', 1000000, 3)
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
```

Second argument is `mode` and by default is equal to `'a'`. [reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler)

Comment: I´m not using any >,< characters in my logger.info(), logger.debug() or logger excetion. That´s the reasion i´m confused about this error. Just in case i checked the old logs. Would it also react if html code was safed in the loggers like <p> Text, Text</p> ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your logs, doesn't matter what kind of message do you try to log. There is a `TypeError` exception being thrown from your `manage.py` script. You didn't post any code, so I cannot tell what exactly you did wrong, but the error message is quite straightforward - you shouldn't do the comparison between string and integer.

Comment: I added the manage.py script. There is no comparison in there.

Comment: There is a comparison, just not explicit. Read my updated answer. BTW, my python3 interpreter showed me the exact line causing a problem: `File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/handlers.py", line 148`. I guess you are using Windows, maybe on Windows python shell is not as helpful as on the Linux systems.

Comment: Yeah I have to use windows... Thanks a lot, it really was the args=() in the RotatingFileHandler